# Dijkstra openmp code in c

Tags: c, testing, tree, dijkstra

Hi i work on openmp and want to test a code of dijkstra algorithm.The code is here[dijkstra_openmp](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/dijkstra_openmp/dijkstra_openmp.c)
.This code is written by John Burkardt and i try to run it.But run time for 1 thread is same by four thread.I have a intel core i3 system that can support 4 threads.I need a test case for it to estimate speed up of code. Available test case is too small.

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. You have provided a link to more than 500 lines of code. Perhaps the question belongs on Codereview, for an analysis of code, written by somebody else.

Comment: We are no consulting site.